# Mix two csv data in one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to mix 2 csv in 1. I converted both in lists because I think is the best way to do it! Also, remember that the `Client` and `Date` are in different columns and maybe the order of data are not the same in both files!

list1 csv:

```
Cliente     Fecha       Status
interlatin  01/01/2018  Alerta Revenue: aumento Subastadas - descenso eCPM y Fillrate
interlatin  31/12/2017  Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Vendidas - Subastadas: Precaucion Fillrate buena Mejora
mmmm        01/01/2018  Alerta Revenue: aumento Subastadas - descenso eCPM y Fillrate
mmmm        31/12/2017  Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Vendidas - Subastadas: Precaucion Fillrate buena Mejora
KKKKK       01/01/2018  Alerta Revenue: aumento Subastadas - descenso eCPM y Fillrate
KKKKK       31/12/2017  Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Vendidas - Subastadas: Precaucion Fillrate buena Mejora
```

list2 csv:

```
Fecha   Cliente Subastas    Impresiones_exchange    Fill_rate   Importe_a_pagar_a_medio ECPM_medio
31/12/2017  interlatin  2141801 303970  14.19   339.12  1.12
01/01/2018  interlatin  308759  70938   22.98   41.9    0.59
31/12/2017  mmmm    2141801 303970  14.19   339.12  1.12
01/01/2018  mmmm    308759  70938   22.98   41.9    0.59
31/12/2017  KKKKK   2141801 303970  14.19   339.12  1.12
01/01/2018  KKKKK   308759  70938   22.98   41.9    0.59
```

What I´m looking for:

```
Cliente Fecha   Subastas    Impresiones_exchange    Fill_rate   Importe_a_pagar_a_medio ECPM_medio Status
interlati 01/01/2018 2141801 303970 14.19 339.12 1.12 Alerta Revenue: aumento Subastadas - descenso eCPM y Fillrate
interlati 31/12/2017 308759 70938 22.98 41.9 0.59 Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Vendidas - Subastadas: Precaucion Fillrate buena Mejora
mmmm     01/01/2018 2141801 303970 14.19 339.12 1.12 Alerta Revenue: aumento Subastadas - descenso eCPM y Fillrate
mmmm     31/12/2017 308759 70938 22.98 41.9 0.59 Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Vendidas - Subastadas: Precaucion Fillrate buena Mejora
KKKKK     01/01/2018 2141801 303970 14.19 339.12 1.12 Alerta Revenue: aumento Subastadas - descenso eCPM y Fillrate
KKKKK     31/12/2017 308759 70938 22.98 41.9 0.59Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Vendidas - Subastadas: Precaucion Fillrate buena Mejora
```

Code:

```
import csv
with open('list1.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    list1 = list(reader)


with open('list2.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    list2 = list(reader)


list1[:] = [','.join(item).split(',') for item in list1]
list2[:] = [','.join(item).split(',') for item in list2]

for i, item in enumerate(list2):
    list1[i].append(item[-1])


with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(list1)
```

Comment: And ? What's your question exactly ? So far you've explained what you had as inputs and what you wanted as outputs and what you've done so far, but that doesn't make a question...

Comment: I can´t do it with the code that I have because I need to search in both lists and for each element on List1 that is on List2 mix in One List! @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: You want to use dicts (OrderedDict if order is important) and not lists, so you can match the lines on client/date. Also the `','.join(item).split(',')` is plain useless, or at least it should be on a proper csv - if those are actually tsv ("tab separated values") you have to tell the csv readers to use tab as a delimiter (cf the csv module's doc).

Comment: Okey and How can I do it? I´m now on python @brunodesthuilliers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to read csv files into dataframes df1 and df2.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
```

Then create a common column:

```
# CREATE A MERGED COLUMN OF CLIENTE AND FECHA IN BOTH DATAFRAMES:
df1['cl_fecha'] = df1['Cliente']+"_"+df1['Fecha']
df2['cl_fecha'] = df2['Cliente']+"_"+df2['Fecha']
```

And merge two dataframes (will automatically merge on common column and order of entries does not matter):

```
# MERGE 2 DATAFRAMES TO GET DESIRED OUTPUT:
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2)
print(df_merged)
```

Output (empty entries are filled by Nan):

```
      Cliente       Fecha                                             Status  \
0  interlatin  01/01/2018  Alerta Revenue: aumento Subastadas - descenso ...   
1  interlatin  31/12/2017  Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Ve...   
2        mmmm  01/01/2018  Alerta Revenue: aumento Subastadas - descenso ...   
3        mmmm  31/12/2017  Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Ve...   
4       KKKKK  01/01/2018  Alerta Revenue: aumento Subastadas - descenso ...   
5       KKKKK  31/12/2017  Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Ve...   

                cl_fecha        Subastas  Impresiones_exchange  Fill_rate  \
0  interlatin_01/01/2018          308759              70938.00      22.98   
1  interlatin_31/12/2017  2141801 303970                 14.19     339.12   
2        mmmm_01/01/2018          308759              70938.00      22.98   
3        mmmm_31/12/2017  2141801 303970                 14.19     339.12   
4       KKKKK_01/01/2018          308759              70938.00      22.98   
5       KKKKK_31/12/2017  2141801 303970                 14.19     339.12   

   Importe_a_pagar_a_medio  ECPM_medio  
0                    41.90        0.59  
1                     1.12         NaN  
2                    41.90        0.59  
3                     1.12         NaN  
4                    41.90        0.59  
5                     1.12         NaN
```

As suggested in comments, use `to_csv` to write to new csv file:

```
df_merged.to_csv('df_merged.csv')
```

Edit: Actually, there is no need to create a merged column. Simply merging two dataframes with `pd.merge(df1, df2)` also produces correct output. Pandas `merge` function also has several options which can be used as needed: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: I recommend adding a `to_csv()` call at the bottom so OP can get the CSV he desires at the end.

Comment: Probably you are not reading csv files properly to dataframes. Use `print(df1)` and `print(df2)` to see each data frame and then use my code.